# как вынести шаблон функции из класса? выдает ошибку, когда я пытаюсь реализовать эту функцию

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, класс

```
class FindMovie
{
public:
 
    template<typename T>
    void printText(T text);
 
private:

};
```

Comment: Покажите как именно пытаетесь, и какую ошибку получаете.

Comment: функцию не видно, когда я ее описываю в другом файле. Хотя без template все работает норм

Comment: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/2752075) В следующий раз не объясняйте, а показывайте код и текст ошибки дословно.

Answer (score 0):

Да так и [реализовать](https://ideone.com/fhyhno) -

```
template<typename T>
void FindMovie::printText(T text)
{
    // Ваш код
}
```